# Braces around scalar initializer error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a simple "font" for numbers to use on my 8x8 display through Arduino. This is just a simple test.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Font{
    public:
        void Number(int num){
            switch(num){
                case 0:
                    bool Font[][5] = {{{{ 0, 1, 0,
                                      1, 0, 1,
                                        1, 0, 1,
                                         1, 0, 1,
                                          0, 1, 0 }}}};
                   break;

               for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                        cout << Font[y][x];
                    }
                    cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Font myFont;
    myFont.Number(0);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this, I get an error saying "13:34: error: braces around scalar initializer for type 'bool'  0, 1, 0 }}}};"

Comment: Why are you putting a for-loop after `break` in a `case`? Are your braces messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you initialize a multidimensional array. You can either use

```
bool Font[][5] = {{ 0, 1, 0 },
                  { 1, 0, 1 },
                  { 1, 0, 1 },
                  { 1, 0, 1 },
                  { 0, 1, 0 }};
```

or

```
bool Font[][5] = {0, 1, 0,
                  1, 0, 1,
                  1, 0, 1,
                  1, 0, 1,
                  0, 1, 0};
```

Comment: Also, when you declare a local variable inside of a `case` block, the `case` needs its own braces, or the compiler will likely complain.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's only if you initialize the variable